# How to simulate pressing F2 button with keyboard focus on treeview in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, focus

I am trying the following:

```
// Key to send   
 var key = Key.F2;       
// Event to send                         
var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; 
TreeControl.RaiseEvent(
               new KeyEventArgs(
                Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                PresentationSource.FromVisual(TreeControl),
                0,
                key) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent }
            );
```

But I can't simulate F2 programmatically this way though `TreeControl` has keyboard focus and if I press F2 immediately after manually it works fine. Please help.

I am trying to call this code in the moment `OnItemSelected` handler is called (not always, when necessary).

Comment: I recently had a similar problem and "solved" it with firing the `PreviewKeyDownEvent` as well. Have you tried to fire both events ? This may be worth a try

Comment: Tried to send Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent and then Keyboard.KeyDownEvent but this doesn't work for me. If you have some working code, please post it.

Comment: Let me post my code as an answer, just so you can compare

Comment: Initially posted code is right and I figured out that it simulates F2 press correctly for treeview. Just another problems not related to this prevented me from seeing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially posted code is right and I figured out that it simulates F2 press correctly for treeview. Just another problems not related to this prevented me from seeing this.

When I tried to simulate F2 click from `OnItemSelected` handler it didn't work but the same from `LayoutUpdated` handler works fine.

So the treeview needs to be fully updated to be ready to accept key presses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
// First: PreviewKeyDown
KeyEventArgs previewArgs = 
   new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 
        0, Key.Down);
previewArgs.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent;
focusedTextBox.RaiseEvent(previewArgs);

// Second: KeyDown
IInputElement newFocusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
KeyEventArgs args = 
   new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 
        0, Key.Down);
args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
newFocusedElement.RaiseEvent(args);
```

There are not a lot of differences between yours and mine anyway...

Comment: Thanks for your code, I think it is right, I figured out my own was right, too. Just there were another problems which prevent me from seeing this.

Comment: So the problem wasn't related to this button-pressing simulation?

Comment: You should close the question or delete it so people won't try to answer to an obsolete problem =)