# How to simulate pressing f2 to make treeview node editable

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm using radtreeview control from Telerik Q3 2010 for winForms and I want to do the following, upon addition of a new node it should be added in Edit mode, well this is not supported in telerik 2010 so I need to simulate pressing F2 to make the node editable.
I found this thread about the same topic: [How to simulate pressing F2 button with keyboard focus on treeview in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581070/how-to-simulate-pressing-f2-button-with-keyboard-focus-on-treeview-in-wpf), but I need to do that in Winform not WPF, can you help me?

**Edit**
I used sendKeys method + tree.BeginEdit but it didn't work out !
This is my code:

```
  private void radButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadTreeNode newNode = new RadTreeNode();
            newNode.Text = "new Cabinet";
            newNode.Tag = "new Cabinet";
            cabinetsTree.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            cabinetsTree.SelectedNode = cabinetsTree.Nodes[cabinetsTree.Nodes.Count-1];
            cabinetsTree.ScrollToBottom(); //To set the focus on the new added node
            cabinetsTree.Focus();
            cabinetsTree.AllowEdit = true;
            SendKeys.Send("{F2}");
            cabinetsTree.BeginEdit();
        }
```

Comment: It will help http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/treeview/add-node-in-edit-mode-with-text.aspx

Comment: EditorInitialized event is not available in Telerik winform Q3 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first allow editing nodes in the control and then use the BeginEdit method of the node:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    RadTreeView tree = new RadTreeView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(tree);
        tree.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        tree.AllowEdit = true;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadTreeNode newNode = new RadTreeNode();
        newNode.Text = "new Cabinet";
        tree.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        newNode.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem that I was calling BeginEdit() on the whole tree not the single node, thanks that really solved it !

Answer (score 1):

The node should have a `BeginEdit()` method that allows the user to rename the node. Based on the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/treeview-working-with-nodes-editing-nodes.html).

> Use the BeginEdit() method to initiate editing on the selected node

Comment: I'm using Winform not ASP.net .. this documentation is for ASP.net

Comment: I couldn't find their winforms documentation but I assumed that if they were using this structure for ASP.NET they would use it on winforms as well. I assume that the method does not exist in winforms then ?

Comment: Found the winforms documentation, take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Please check my question again, I've added the code and used "BeginEdit" but it didn't work !

Comment: Why are you sending the f2 key ?

Comment: The node becomes editable when you call BeginEdit(). So there is no reason to send f2.

Comment: No it didn't I tried to call BeginEdit() but the node didn't get editable.

Comment: Try remove the ScrollToBottom() and/or Focus() to see if that is what's conflicting with it. I assume you are not handling the AfterLabelEdit and BeforeLabelEdit correct ? It should be working.

Comment: I've deleted focus and kept scroll besides calling BeginEdit on the new added node, and it worked fine thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this by catching the keypress events on your keyboard and setting the editmode to true whenever you get the f2 key pressed.

Comment: The user should not press F2, I just want to press one button that will add a new node to the tree in edit mode.